# Spring Boot project hosted on Heroku - Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 90 seconds of launch

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, heroku

**I have read many similar questions on stackoverflow and nothing helped me.**

I have created a spring boot maven backend project and hosted on heroku.

But, when I try to call from the frontend , it shows an error like this in the browser.
`GET https://hoyamu-springboot-backend.herokuapp.com/fetch/bag 503`

When I view the log of heroku it shows an error like this. `Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 90 seconds of launch` . I did everything and nothing works.

My files are as below,

**Heroku Application Log**

```
020-08-08T21:32:21.232432+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-08-08T21:32:25.103258+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java -Dserver.port=48348 $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/hoyamu-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`
2020-08-08T21:32:27.226023+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2020-08-08T21:32:27.230034+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
2020-08-08T21:32:28.818160+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-08-08T21:32:28.818210+00:00 app[web.1]:   .   ____          _            __ _ _
2020-08-08T21:32:28.818211+00:00 app[web.1]:  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
2020-08-08T21:32:28.818214+00:00 app[web.1]: ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
2020-08-08T21:32:28.818294+00:00 app[web.1]:  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
2020-08-08T21:32:28.818323+00:00 app[web.1]:   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
2020-08-08T21:32:28.818414+00:00 app[web.1]:  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
2020-08-08T21:32:28.819695+00:00 app[web.1]:  :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.6.RELEASE)
2020-08-08T21:32:28.819727+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-08-08T21:32:29.047717+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-08 21:32:29.044  INFO 4 --- [           main] com.udith.hoyamu.HoyamuApplication       : Starting HoyamuApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on 50382c68-eaab-4b3c-ac0c-a881a18e4a0b with PID 4 (/app/target/hoyamu-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by u8138 in /app)
2020-08-08T21:32:29.048863+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-08 21:32:29.048  INFO 4 --- [           main] com.udith.hoyamu.HoyamuApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-08-08T21:32:30.083462+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-08 21:32:30.081  INFO 4 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-08-08T21:32:30.224960+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-08 21:32:30.224  INFO 4 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 130ms. Found 18 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-08-08T21:32:31.310818+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-08 21:32:31.310  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 48348 (http)
2020-08-08T21:32:31.327532+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-08 21:32:31.327  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-08-08T21:32:31.327720+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-08 21:32:31.327  INFO 4 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.33]
2020-08-08T21:32:31.405048+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-08 21:32:31.404  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-08-08T21:32:31.405289+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-08 21:32:31.405  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2272 ms
2020-08-08T21:32:31.669531+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-08 21:32:31.669  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-08-08T21:32:31.931057+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-08 21:32:31.930  INFO 4 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.12.Final
2020-08-08T21:32:32.109028+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-08 21:32:32.108  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-08-08T21:32:32.249430+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-08 21:32:32.249  INFO 4 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-08-08T21:32:33.786599+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-08 21:32:33.786  INFO 4 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-08-08T21:32:33.850851+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-08-08 21:32:33.850  INFO 4 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
2020-08-08T21:33:55.347291+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 90 seconds of launch
2020-08-08T21:33:55.368253+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2020-08-08T21:33:55.465503+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2020-08-08T21:33:55.499546+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

2020-08-08T21:50:58.187914+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/fetch/bag" host=hoyamu-springboot-backend.herokuapp.com request_id=db721f39-aab3-4a3f-82e9-6495dc6bc7a8 fwd="112.135.40.125" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

**Procfile**

`web: java -Dserver.port=$PORT $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/hoyamu-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

**application.properties**

````
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://remotemysql.com:3306/MMgqawaw
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true


```
What should I do?
````

Comment: remove `server.port=${PORT:8080}`

Comment: @ThomasAndolf I tried even without ```server.port=${PORT:8080}```  . but nothing worked.

Comment: Usually this error is due to unavailable ports. Can you try to specify a different port like 5001 or 3000?

Comment: Usually why heroku cant bind to the port is because your app is not starting properly, check the sql connection. If you are using heroku sql is not mysql, they are running postgres. My guess is that app can’t start because the database connection is failing. The sql dialect in the log is different from the one set in your properties for example.

Comment: @NishānWickramarathna The port is auto  assigned by the heroku and the issue says that it cannot be bound to the app.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf Um npt using heroku sql.  I don't know how to check whether the database connection is failing or not. But, it should be something related to the database connection, because when um running this app locally, it works fine and shows some sql commads running just after the database is connected. Here, I cannot see such sql commads, may be because the db connection has failed.  Even in  my local machine, the sql dialect is similar to the one in the logs. So, it can be guessed that the issue is not because of the dialect too.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf ,  and, even in my local machine, it takes around two minutes to get connected to remote database. But, here I don't know whether the app is waiting a sufficient time till the connection is made.   Do you have any suggestion you would like to make ?  thanks in advance.

Comment: @UdithIndrakantha The port heroku assigns is 80 for all request forwarding, I'm asking you to set the application port explicitly. Try that and see if it works. `server.port=8081` in `application.properties`

Comment: @NishānWickramarathna I explicitly set the port too as you have shown. but, nothing works . I cannot understand why this gives such an error when everything is set finely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After several small surveys, I could find the solution for my issue.

The error `Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 90 seconds of launch`  can happen  due to two reasons.

1. Actually the app cannot bind the port as it is not defined in the procfile properly.
   You can find solutions for that by reading some stackoverflow questions.
   In brief, procfile should look like this:

(replace <BUILT_APP_NAME_HERE> with your app name after deployed)

`web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar -Dserver.port=$PORT target/<BUILT_APP_NAME_HERE>.jar`

[or]

When giving * , you don't need to specify the name

`web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar -Dserver.port=$PORT target/*.jar`

[or]

`web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=production target/<BUILT_APP_NAME_HERE>.jar --port $PORT`

2. Second reason is, as shown in the error, it tries to bind the port after 90 seconds (for some apps it is 60 secs)  of launch, even though the app has not yet fully started. By default, for java apps ,heroku has set a limit of 90 secs as the boot time. If Heroku cannot bind the port during that time, the app is marked as crashed.
   Here , in my project, it takes another little time for making the connection with remote database , but heroku doesn't wait till the db connection is made as its boot time is 90 secs.

The solution for this is, we have to increase the boot time of the app.  you can do this by following this link. ( Sometimes this link gives errors, then try with another browser or with your mobile phone's browser)

https://tools.heroku.support/limits/boot_timeout

However, it is not recommended to increase the boot time more 120secs.

But, in real case, you should find the solution  why it takes much time to make the db connection.

Comment: this `web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar -Dserver.port=$PORT target/*.jar` works for me

Comment: you just saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

i was able to run my spring mvc app with this Procfile content:

web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port $PORT target/*.war

this is the deployed app: http://duckingrace.herokuapp.com/web/canvasv1

this is the source code: https://github.com/fajaralmu/java-websocket1